# RegEx Expression to validate TextBox data

Tags: asp.net, regex

The validator should allow only alphabetic characters (a-z and A-Z), dots(.),comma(,), slash(/) and hyphen (-). Please help to to find out one.  Or tell me how to create one customized to my specifications.

I have tried `[a-zA-Z,-/.]` and it works but my requirements only allow for a maximum of 1 of each of the non-letter characters I specified (.,/-).

Comment: I edited your question slightly to help clean it up, but your original word `alphabets` is unclear.  I assume you mean traditional letters [a-z] & [A-Z], but not numerals.  Please confirm

Comment: Also, as you are relatively new on SO, asking questions without doing your own research is not encouraged.  A good question should provide whatever code or example that you have tried.  We'll be happy to help you make it work (or work better).  I would suggest you start with your own RegEx expression to let us know what you tried and what isn't working.  I have found [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info) and invaluable reference in the past

Comment: THE LETTERS [A-Z], [a-z], comma(,), dots(.),comma(,), slash(/) and hyphen (-)

Comment: i tried [a-zA-Z,-/.] but it allows multiple dots, slashes, hyphens, commas. I want the alphabets can repeat but these four special characters should not repeat in the expression.. Please help me out..

Comment: Ok, so that is important information that should be in the question.  You want any number of letters that can repeat, but you only want a maximum of 1 of the punctuation characters you specified?

Answer (score 0):

Try: `^[A-Za-z]*[-a-zA-Z,/.]{1}[A-Za-z]*$`

## Explanation

- `^` Anchor to start of string
- `[A-Za-z]*` may be surrounded by multiple letters
- `[-a-zA-Z,/.]{1}` Only one of the enclosed characters
- `[A-Za-z]*` may be surrounded by multiple letters
- `$` Anchor to end of string